# Textarea content not updating dynamically with JS/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Gridster for webpage.The widgets have images on it.These images can be added and deleted with `+` and `X` button.

There are two `<textarea>` fields on widgets.

One with

```
class="hoverinformation" \\ it captures title attribute for image
```

and other with

```
class="imagenames"\\it captures image src.
```

I have written a code to dynamically update the text area when an image is deleted or added to it.

**Problems with the output of the code written**

1. When I delete an image the `src` and `title` gets deleted but an unecessary `,` is remaining
2. When I manually add an image the both `<textarea>` updated but when I delete that image that image only `<textarea>` with `class="imagenames"` get updated.
   `<textarea>` with `class="hoverinformation "` does not gets updated.
3. When I delete all the images which are generated from `JSON`(that are present initially when user loads the page) and then if I add images manually then both the `<textarea>` do not get updated
   (When I check in `inspect element` both `textarea` are dynamically updated)

My Code for deletion of image and updating text area

```
$(document).on('click', '.removediv', function () {

//For textarea with class 'imagenames'

  var imagename = $(this).parent().siblings('.imagenames');
  var text   = imagename.val();
  var imgSrc = $(this).prev().attr("src");
  imagename.val(text.replace(imgSrc, ""));

//For textarea with class 'hoverinformation'

  var hoverinformation  = $(this).parent().siblings('.hoverinformation');
  var text   = hoverinformation.val();
  var title = $(this).prev().attr("title");
  hoverinformation.val(text.replace(title,""));

$(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();
  });
```

My code that manually adds image and update both `<textarea>`

```
var parentLI;
$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
                parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
            $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('preselect');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('preselect');
        selectedImageSRC = $(this).attr('src');
      })
    });

$('#add-image').click(function(){
    parentLI.append('<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src="'+selectedImageSRC+'" title="Manual Addition"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div>');

  parentLI.children('.imagenames').append(', '+selectedImageSRC);
  parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').append(', '+"Manual Addition");

  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
});
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dwkpstuz/)

I am not understanding why there is such a weird behavior seen.Any help will be great.

Comment: First fix: Don't use `.append` to set the textarea text. Use `.val()` instead.

Comment: Here's how: https://jsfiddle.net/dwkpstuz/8/

Comment: That does solve the 3 problem .Any idea for getting rid of those ,

Answer (score 0):

this way you can get rid of ","

```
$(document).on('click', '.removediv', function () {
  var imagename = $(this).parent().siblings('.imagenames');
  var text   = imagename.val();
  var imgSrc = $(this).prev().attr("src");
  text = removestring(text, imgSrc);
  imagename.val(text);


  var hoverinformation  = $(this).parent().siblings('.hoverinformation');
  var text   = hoverinformation.val();
  var title = $(this).prev().attr("title");

  text = removestring(text, title);

  hoverinformation.val(text);



  $(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();


});



function removestring(text, title) {
    var arr = text.split(",");
  var index = arr.indexOf(title);
  if (index > -1) {
         arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
    text = arr.join(",");
  return text;
}
```